# tcp socket in android 3.0

Tags: android

I have a little problem with sockets. In Android 2.0 its working very well but when I create project with Android 3.0 API it throws errors and don't work. Are there big changes in using socket in 3.x API ?

My code is quite simple:

```
try {
    Nsocket = new Socket("192.168.1.101", 2000);
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(Nsocket.getOutputStream());
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(Nsocket.getInputStream());
    Nsocket.setSoTimeout(150);            
}
catch(UnknownHostException en) {
}
catch(IOException en) {
}
finally {
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which exception are you getting?

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException      and then: at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077), at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:368) ... and few more :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet to your code before calling network functions.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {
              StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
              StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  
            }
```

Note: Add Network permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.